# ASP.Net MVC random, Controllers and views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been having trouble creating a `ASP.NET MVC` program that will randomly select a student and randomly select a question and for some reason I cant get it to work in the .cshtml file. Am I doing something wrong? Also i get this Error

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'QuizProgramMVC.Models.Student', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'QuizProgramMVC.Models.StudentQuestion'."`using QuizProgramMVC.Models;

**Controller**

```
public class QuizController : Controller
{
    public QuizController TheQuiz { get; set; }

    // GET: Quiz
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        StudentQuestion sq = new StudentQuestion();

        return View(sq);
    }

    public ActionResult QuizProgram()
    {        
        Student program = new Student();

        return View(program);
    }

}
```

**View**

```
@model QuizProgramMVC.Models.StudentQuestion
@using QuizProgramMVC.Models;

@{

    Layout = null;
 }

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>QuizProgram</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <h1>Quiz Program</h1>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Question</th>
                                    <th>Answer</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (Question q in Model.Questions)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @q.Quest
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @q.Answer
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <br/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (Student s in Model.Students)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @s.FirstName
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @s.LastName
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <br/>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div>
                Type Answer: <input id="param1" name="param1" type="text" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't  the error message obvious ? You are passing a different type from your action method than expected. Instead of the Student object, you need to pass an object of `StudentQuestion` because your view is strongly typed to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are calling the same view page with different model.

```
public ActionResult QuizProgram()
{        
    Student program = new Student();//Here you need to pass the StudentQuestion to the view.
    return View(program);
}
```

Calling the above View Page(.cshtml) via **QuizProgram()** throws an error because in that view page you defined the model as

```
@model QuizProgramMVC.Models.StudentQuestion
```

It does not allow other ViewModels because it is **strongly-typed** View.